Issue with manual url path acessibility with firebase, router and contextAPI
I want to access routes manually by typing the URL address in the browser if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, I want to redirect the page to the login page. Additionally, I want the Log In and Sign Up pages to be accessible by typing their URL paths manually public in a browser. However, currently, I am redirected to the login page every time I try to access any of the private routes manually, whether I am logged in or not.
this is my Router:
const Main = () => {
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <App />,
        children: [
         
          {
            path: "/",
            element: <GroupMenu />,
          },
          {
            path: "/group-content",
            element: <GroupContent />,
          },
          {
            path: "/dashboard",
            element: <Dashboard />,
          },

          {
            path: "/sign-in",
            element: <LogIn />,
          },
          {
            path: "/sign-up",
            element: <Register />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    { basename: "/thatswhy_items_counter/" }
  );

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};


this is my App component(hier i displaying my all components from router component):
function App() {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <Button variant="contained">Something</Button>
      <PrivateRoute>
        <Outlet />
      </PrivateRoute>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}

This is my PrivateRoute component, that should redirect users to log in page if they are not yet logged in:
  const currentUser = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.currentUser);
  console.log(currentUser);
  return currentUser?.email ? children : <Navigate to="/sign-in" />;
}

and lastly i have a context provider, that shares states and function with other components:
export const ContextAPI = createContext<null | TContextAPI>(null);

const ContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const { signUpValues, SignUpInputConstructor, handleRegister, signUpError } = useAuth();
  const { logInValues, SignInInputConstructor, handleLogIn, logInError } = useLogIn();
  const { handleLogout, logOutError } = useLogOut();

  const vals: TContextAPI = {
    handleLogout,
    logOutError,
    setLoading,
    currentUser,
    signUpValues,
    SignUpInputConstructor,
    handleRegister,
    loading,
    signUpError,
    logInValues,
    SignInInputConstructor,
    handleLogIn,
    logInError,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
      } else {
        setCurrentUser(null);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });
    console.log(currentUser);
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return <ContextAPI.Provider value={vals}> {!loading && children} </ContextAPI.Provider>;
};

I also have a github repo, if this information is not enought: project_repo
I've tried to change my router structure and create something like a lobby for users who are not logged in, but it didn't solve my problem with manual access in a browser. I have also tried to put my PrivateRouter component as a parent for all private routes, but it gave me the same result..

The initial currentUser state value is the same as your "unauthenticated" user value, so when the app mounts it treats all users a unauthenticated and redirects. Additionally, you have wrapped all of App's nested routes in PrivateRoute, so it looks like your signin/signup routes will be inaccessible to unauthenticated users. You'll want to separate these routes from those you want to protect.

@DrewReese , thank you very much for your answer. Do you know how I can handle the initial currentUser to be "authenticated"? I've tried to fix it, but I always get a "null" value in my currentUser state when entering the URL manually. After a few seconds, this state turns into an object with my authentication data.

My recommendation is to use an initial state value that is neither a user object for "authenticated" and null for "unauthenticated", e.g. something like using undefined for the initial state, and then explicitly checking for undefined to guard rendering the protected content or the redirect. Does this make sense? Perhaps this simpler answer specific to using onAuthStateChanged helps illustrate it more clearly.

@DrewReese, thank you again for providing this information with these simple examples. It took me some time to figure it out, but now it is working. However, I still don't understand exactly why my project didn't work until I set my currentUser to undefined. Did this happen because useEffect was not updating this state since it contained "null"? But now it is working, and I really appreciate it.

now i handle my currentUser like this:
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

and my PrivateRoute looks like this:
  const currentUser = useContextSelector(ContextAPI, (v) => v?.currentUser);
  if (currentUser === undefined) return null;
  return currentUser ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/sign-in" />;
};```

The useEffect hook runs at the end of the render cycle, so for each initial render cycle the code "sees" and uses that initial state. The useEffect hook enqueues a state update, triggers a rerender, and then the component "sees" that updated state. With your original code it's too late by then, the redirect already happened.
